# why my object contentDocument returns null?

Tags: javascript, svg

My goal is by scrolling mouse wheel, to change a viewBox attribute in a SVG, which retrieved through websocket from the API server.  The way I do this is the following:

1. generate

   `<object id={"std-chart"}
   class="mouse-wheel-pannable"
   type="image/svg+xml"
   />`
2. when get data `svgStr` from websocket, dynamically put that in the `<object>` element.

   `let obj = document.getElementById('std-chart');
   var objUrl = 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,'+ svgStr;
   obj.setAttributeNS(null,'data',objUrl);`

where `svgStr` is something like:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1081" height="184" viewBox="0 0 1081 184"  > 
<path d="M 0.0 98.7 L 0.3 98.7 .../> 
</svg>
```

**Q1. I am not quite sure why I need to add `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,` in front of the `svgStr`. If I don't, the picture cannot be shown.**

3. in my mouseWheelScroll() function, I try to find this svg element and change its viewBox. However I cannot find the svg element, because `contentDocument` returns null.

   `var svgObjs = document.getElementsByClassName("mouse-wheel-pannable");
   var svgObj = svgObjs[0].contentDocument;                    //svgObj returns null 
   var svg = svgObj.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];            //error here
   svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'viewBox', someNewViewBox);`

   **Question. How can I get a valid contentDocument. i.e. `<svg>` element, so that I can change the viewBox?**

thank you.

I tried to use `<embed>` instead of `<object>`, from the Chrome console I saw the embed item, however still how to get the underneath `<svg>`? Is that `<svg>` shown in the following picture still valid? 
[Please click here to see the chrome console for it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WIkX.png)

thank you.

Did some more tests. If I set `<object data=xxxxxx.svg/>` at the first beginning, i.e. if I store the svg content in a file and loaded in when initialize `<object>`, everything works perfect.  Then I think the question is that how to dynamically let `<object>` to "reload" the svg content.

thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> Q1. I am not quite sure why I need to add data:image/svg+xml;utf8

The `data` attribute of an `<object>` has to be a URL.  The string `<svg>...</svg>` is not a URL.

Prefixing it with `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,` turns it into a [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). The `image/svg+xml` is the MIME type which tells the browser this URL is an SVG.  The `utf8` part tells the browser how the text is encoded.

BTW, Data URLs have the same rules that other URLs have. SVGs can contain characters that are illegal in URLs.  So you should be URL encoding the SVG when you create the Data URL.

```
var objUrl = 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,'+ encodeURI( svgStr );
```

> Question. How can I get a valid contentDocument. i.e.  element, so that I can change the viewBox?

You can't Not for a Data URL at least.  Data URLs are treated as if they are on a different domain. And you can't get the `contentDocument` for cross domain objects.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#origin:document-4

"If the Document was generated from a `data:` URL
  A unique opaque origin assigned when the Document is created."

> Then I think the question is that how to dynamically let  to "reload" the svg content.

Why do you need to use an `<object>`?  Why not just insert your SVG directly into the page?